# COPY to a table with composite type columns

Tags: postgresql

everybody.
I'm trying to execute COPY function on a table having some composite type columns.
Suppose, we have the next entities:

```
CREATE TYPE point AS (first real, second real);
CREATE TABLE a(
 x1 point,
 x2 point 
);
```

How can I add some records to the table "a" using COPY function? Postgres rejects my command

```
COPY a (x1.fisrt) FROM 'filename'
```

writing that the column 'x1.first' doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't think you can put data into the field of a composite type. You can only put data into a "complete" column of a table. You probably need to format the values in the text file so that both fields of the point type are provided (and why did you create your own point type? Postgres already has one built-in)

Comment: Thanks, I've created this type just as an brief example.

Comment: If the file contains only a subset of the composite type fields then copy to an intermediary table and do an update from there.